# Is it possible to monitor 2 tomcat servers using psi-probe?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7, probe

Is it possible to monitor more than one tomcat server using psi-probe?

If not, is there any other open source tool for doing so?

We deployed our web application in 6 different tomcat severs. We are using a VIP as load balancer. Basically I want to monitor all these web app instance's sessions using one single probe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try using the javamelody open source project. It has a web app that collect all differents instances and gives a web app console to manage.

http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/